# Backbone update model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-model

In backbone I have created the following models,collections, and views

`var sensor= Backbone.Model.extend({})`

`var sensorCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: sensor
})`

`var sensors= new sensorCollection;`

`var SensorView =Backbone.View.extend({})`

`var AppView =Backbone.View.extend({})`

`var App = new AppView`

I also have this PHP socket running:

```
var conn = new ab.Session('ws:localhost:8080', function() {
    conn.subscribe('temperature', function(topic, data) {
        console.log('Current temperature reading' + data.temperature);
        sensor.set({temperature:data.temperature});//Attempting to change backbone model

    });
}, function() {
    console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
}, {
    'skipSubprotocolCheck' : true
});
```

I am attempting to change/update the model with the temperature reading coming in from socket.  As you can see  I have tried by `sensor.set` and also tried the following:

`App.model.set`

`This.model.set`

`App.sensor.set`

And each different way it either says undefined or something about the function not found.  Am I missing something here? They are all declared in the same `$(function(){}`

How do I update my backbone model from my Autobahn socket function?

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Model.extend({})` returns a class, not an instance. You should write instead:

```
var Sensor = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var sensor = new Sensor();

sensor.on('change:temperature', function (temperature) {
  console.log('new temperature: ' + temperature);
});

var conn = new ab.Session('ws:localhost:8080', function() {
    conn.subscribe('temperature', function(topic, data) {
        console.log('Current temperature reading' + data.temperature);
        sensor.set({temperature:data.temperature});//Attempting to change backbone model

    });
}, function() {
    console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
}, {
    'skipSubprotocolCheck' : true
});
```